# How to access a nested function externally in JS/React?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, scope, closures

I'm having some trouble with scoping functions. I'm trying to get the value of "item" but I'm getting undefined when I try to access it outside of the function. How can I make "item" accessible from the outside onLinkClicked()? I need to be able to use item in my render.

```
   onLinkClicked() {

   var parent = this.state.username
       //console.log(this.state.username)
   var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
       serverUrl: 'https://cs63.salesforce.com',
       accessToken: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
   })
   conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Contact WHERE LastName='" + parent + "'",
       function(err, result) {
           if (err) {
               return console.error(err);
           }

             var a = result
              a.records.forEach(function(item) {
               result = (item.Name + ' ' + item.Phone);

               console.log(item) // I'm trying to get the value of item, which outputs correctly here

           });

       }
   )

   console.log(item) //Here I get undefined due to being out of scope, how can I access item?.

  }

 render () {

return (
    <div className='menubox' id='menubox'>
  <div className='searchbar-container'>
    <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      <input
        type='text'
        size='25'
        placeholder='Contact Last Name'
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.state.username} />
        <button
        type='submit'
        onClick={this.onLinkClicked.bind(this)}>
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
   </div>
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: item } }>
   </div>
  </div>

 )
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, spaces and semicolons. Your code is beyond unreadable.

Comment: I do hope nobody's user name happens to be `Robert'; DROP TABLE Contact;--`

Comment: I'm running this locally, once I have everything working I'll put an escape in to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a global variable where you store your result. If you are using react (the react-class you are using is not entirely shown) you should use `this.setState` to set a state and use it elsewhere. You can not use item after the conn.query-method as conn.query is asynchronous. If you want to do processing with it that do it in the callback.

I assumed you need item in the render-function. With the state this is easily possible.

Please note that i changed the `function`-definitions to lambda-expressions (`() => {}`). This is necessary in order to use `this` within the callback.

```
... () {
  // ...
  conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Contact WHERE LastName='" + parent + "'",
           (err, result) => {
             if (err) {
               return console.error(err);
             }

             var a = result;
             a.records.forEach((item) => {
               result = (item.Name + ' ' + item.Phone);
               this.setState({item : item});
             });

           };
          );

  // You will never be able to get item here, because you are using an
  // asynchronous function. If you want to use item further in this
  // function you have to use it within the callback of conn.query.
  console.log(item);
};

render () {
  // Nevertheless you can use this.state.item here. I assume this is
  // what you want.
  return ( // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: You should use functionnal setState, like this `this.setState(() => ({ item : item})` because setState is asynchronous and have some pitfalls

Comment: @VincentTaing your function is asynchronous as well and uses the same value as well because of the closure. I do not see a difference.

Comment: It is dangerous because passing an object will make the state in a pending state, which means the state won't be immediately mutated. If you try to setState from somewhere else in the app you will encounter some conflict and you won't know why. If you pass to setState a function instead of an object, it will be synchronously mutated. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: @VincentTaing As far as i can see the danger is only present if you are using the current state or the props. Neither is used here, so there is no need for the syntactical overhead.